# WCSession is not paired getting error in iPhone to iWatch simulators to share data between in Swift

Tags: swift, iphone, watchkit, watchconnectivity

I am working on workouts application for iWatch. I am trying to sharing data from watch to phone, But, I am getting WCSession is not paired error.

ViewController.Swift

```
    import UIKit
    import WatchConnectivity

    class ViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var textFieldMessage : UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var butt

onSend : UIButton!
    var wcSession : WCSession!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        wcSession = WCSession.default
        wcSession.delegate = self
        wcSession.activate()
    }

    //MARK: - Button Actions

    @IBAction func clickSendMessage(_ sender : UIButton) {

        let message = ["message" : textFieldMessage.text!]
        do {
            try wcSession.updateApplicationContext(message)
        } catch {
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - WCSessionDelegate

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        NSLog("%@", "activationDidCompleteWith activationState:\(activationState) error:\(String(describing: error))")
    }

    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("%@", "sessionDidBecomeInactive: \(session)")
    }

    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("%@", "sessionDidDeactivate: \(session)")
    }

    func sessionWatchStateDidChange(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("%@", "sessionWatchStateDidChange: \(session)")
    }
}
```

InterfaceController.Swift

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

    var session : WCSession?
    @IBOutlet weak var sessionLabel : WKInterfaceLabel!

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()

        session = WCSession.default
        session?.delegate = self
        session?.activate()
    }

    // MARK: - WCSessionDelegate

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        NSLog("%@", "activationDidCompleteWith activationState:\(activationState) error:\(String(describing: error))")
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {
        NSLog("didReceiveApplicationContext : %@", applicationContext)
        sessionLabel.setText(applicationContext["message"] as? String)
    }

}
```

The error I am getting is below

> [WC] -[WCSession xpcConnectionRestoredWithState:]_block_invoke
>   dropping as pairingIDs no longer match. pairingID (null), client
>   pairingID: (null)

How to fix this, Any suggestions?